# function to sum total values in dictionary

Tags: python, shopping-cart

I have a dict with several entries for the value.

```
   inventory = {847502: ['APPLES 1LB', 2, 50], 847283: ['OLIVE OIL', 1, 100], 839529: ['TOMATOS 1LB', 4, 25], 
                 483946: ['MILK 1/2G', 2, 50], 493402: ['FLOUR 5LB', 2, 50], 485034: ['BELL PEPPERS 1LB', 3, 50]}
```

I want to create a function to get the total of the value items ie. sum((2*50)+ (1*100) etc...)
I think I'm nearly there but this seems to only add the first value....

```
def total_and_number(dict):
    for values in dict.values():
        #print(values[1]*values[2])
        total =0
        total += (values[1]* values[2])
        return(total)


total_and_number(inventory)
```

Comment: `return` should be put out of `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Return and total rows were misplaced. This returns 650.

```
inventory = {847502: ['APPLES 1LB', 2, 50],
             847283: ['OLIVE OIL', 1, 100], 839529: ['TOMATOS 1LB', 4, 25], 
             483946: ['MILK 1/2G', 2, 50], 493402: ['FLOUR 5LB', 2, 50],
             485034: ['BELL PEPPERS 1LB', 3, 50]
}

def total_and_number(dict):
    total = 0
    for values in dict.values():
        total += values[1]*values[2]
    return(total)

total_and_number(inventory)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
def total_and_number(d):
    tot = 0
    for k, v in d.items():
        tot += v[1]*v[2]
    return tot

total_and_number(inventory)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define variable total out of for loop codes.

```
result = sum([ value[1]*value[2] for value in inventory.values()]
```

or

```
def total_and_number(dict):
    total =0
    for values in dict.values():
       #print(values[1]*values[2])
       total += (values[1]* values[2])
    return total
total_and_number(inventory)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x = {
    847502: ['APPLES 1LB', 2, 50], 847283: ['OLIVE OIL', 1, 100], 839529: ['TOMATOS 1LB', 4, 25], 
    483946: ['MILK 1/2G', 2, 50], 493402: ['FLOUR 5LB', 2, 50], 485034: ['BELL PEPPERS 1LB', 3, 50]
}

print(sum([x[i][1]*x[i][2] for i in x.keys()]))
```

**output :**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
650
```

**EDIT :** For your own code you need to take out `total=0` and `return total` from the loop.

```
def total_and_number(dict):
    total = 0
    for values in dict.values():
        total += (values[1]*values[2])
    return(total)


print(total_and_number(x))
```

Output :

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
650
```

Comment: Using `x.values()` is easier, no?

Comment: It is for sure but the author of the question has already used it and I just wanted to approach from a different side in order to benefit other who does not know this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like every value is a list (though it should probably be a tuple) of:

```
itemname, qty, eachprice
```

So it should be easy enough to iterate through and sum directly:

```
sum(qty*eachprice for _, qty, eachprice in inventory.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try and access the items through their key values:

```
def total_and_number(dictis):
    total = 0
    for key in list(dictis.keys()):
        print(key)
        total += (dictis[key][1]*dictis[key][2])
    return(total)
```

It does return the expected value you need.

Comment: This doesn't improve anything, the problem is the return statement occurring on the first iteration of the loop, and total being reset to 0 each iteration.